# animation.Funcanimation() Matplotlib / How to use it properly?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

Sample Data:

---

```
Area    Africa  Asia    Europe  N_America   S_America   Australia   Antarctica
Y1961   -0.17   0.49    8.74    0.17    1.16    1.51    2.80
Y1962   -0.40   -0.08   3.00    -0.58   -1.39   1.23    -2.27
Y1963   0.64    2.66    1.03    3.72    1.39    -1.14   1.35
Y1964   -1.53   -1.66   -5.23   -2.85   -2.17   -0.22   -3.66
Y1965   -1.97   -0.33   -4.30   -5.94   -0.15   1.27    -0.99
```

Code:

---

```
n=len(Continents.index)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
def action(curr): 
    global colors
    global cmap
    global Continents
    global color_dict
    if curr==n:
        a.event_source.stop()
    CURR=Continents.iloc[curr] 
    ax = plt.gca()
    ticks(curr)
    bars = plt.bar(Continents.columns,CURR,color=[color_dict[country] for country in Continents.columns]) 
    for bar,height in zip(bars,CURR):
        return bar.set_height(height)
         
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,action, interval=100, frames=np.array(range(0,n)))
```

When I use my action function separately, it works, but I cannot use it in animation.Funcanimation() function. I want to change bar heights according to year.

[image]

Comment: Without toy-like sample data, I'm not sure what you want to animate. Make it clear what kind of data you want to use, what you want to animate around it, and what you want to convey.

Comment: Okay, my bad I am adding. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The colors are specified with 'colors'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Area    Africa  Asia    Europe  N_America   S_America   Australia   Antarctica
Y1961   -0.17   0.49    8.74    0.17    1.16    1.51    2.80
Y1962   -0.40   -0.08   3.00    -0.58   -1.39   1.23    -2.27
Y1963   0.64    2.66    1.03    3.72    1.39    -1.14   1.35
Y1964   -1.53   -1.66   -5.23   -2.85   -2.17   -0.22   -3.66
Y1965   -1.97   -0.33   -4.30   -5.94   -0.15   1.27    -0.99
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
# from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

idx = df.columns[1:].tolist()
colors = ['m','g','c','k','y']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,6), ylim=(-10, 10))
# ax.set_xticklabels(idx, rotation=30)
    
def animate(i):
    ax.cla()
    ax.bar(idx, df.iloc[i,1:], color=colors)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)
    return fig,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=5, interval=200, repeat=False)
plt.show()
# anim.save('bar_ani.gif', writer='pillow')
```

[image]